# Section and Subsection Heading Style

Tags: sectioning, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/formatting-section-titles)

How can I change the format of `section`, `subsection` and ... to something like below?

**2.1 | Greenhouse Effect**

Comment: See, for example, [the answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/formatting-section-titles).  With `titlesec` you could use something like: `\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\bf}{\thesection\hspace{5pt}$\vert$}{5pt}{}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default formatting of section heading counters is performed by the macro `\@seccntformat`, which is defined in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) as

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
```

This prints the counter and inserts `\quad`. You can adapt this to print the counter and insert something else, like

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace*{0.5em}$|$\hspace*{0.5em}}
```

This would still have a `\quad`-like feel, only with the insertion of a pipe:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
% \def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}% Default
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace*{0.5em}$|$\hspace*{0.5em}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Greenhouse effect}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Of course, this would hold far *all* section from the level of `\section` downward, whenever you have a numbered heading. Unnumbered headings will not be affected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) to help with this; I've used the [`lipsum`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lipsum/lipsum.pdf) package for sample text and I found `\textpipe` from the `tipa` package from [The comprehensive sysmbols list](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tipa}

% custom section
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection\hskip 9pt\textpipe\hskip 9pt}
{0pt}
{}

\begin{document}

\section{Greenhouse effect}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```