# What does \secdef do?

Tags: macros, sectioning, koma-script

The definition of the `chapter` command in KOMA-class `scrbook` is:

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter
}
```

I am wondering what `\secdef` does.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`\secdef` is a utility command; if a definition is in the form

```
\def\foo{<tokens>\secdef\fooA\fooB}
```

a call of `\foo` will do

```
 <tokens>\fooA
```

while calling `\foo*` will do

```
<tokens>\fooB
```

This is because the definition of `\secdef` is

```
\def\secdef#1#2{\@ifstar{#2}{\@dblarg{#1}}}
```

Therefore, leaving aside the `<tokens>` that may precede the execution of `\secdef`, we get

```
\@ifstar{\fooB}{\@dblarg{\fooA}}
```

If `\foo*` is called, `\fooB` is executed, otherwise TeX does

```
\@dblarg{\fooA}
```

and so `\fooA` *must* be defined in a special way:

```
\def\fooA[#1]#2{...}
```

like `\@chapter` is. The `\@dblarg` trick basically examines the next token; if it is `[`, then we are in a situation such as

```
\foo[X]{Y}
```

and LaTeX will do

```
\fooA[X]{Y}
```

Otherwise we have

```
\foo{Y}
```

and `\@dblarg` will arrange things in such a way that TeX will eventually see

```
\fooA[Y]{Y}
```

Change `\foo` into `\chapter`, `\fooA` into `\@chapter` and `\fooB` into `\@schapter` to better understand the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Oh... I guess I got it on my own: `\secdef` seems to switch between `\chapter` and `\chapter*` call, so you can define in the example above for each case an own macro `\@chapter` (non-star case) or `\@schapter` (star-case).