# Q: How to globally add space before subsubsection* headings in Lyx?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, lyx, koma-script

How do I set the document to add extra space above each subsubsection*?

Does one redefine the subsection command in the preamble, like the following?

[Formatting section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/formatting-section-titles)

I am using KOMA report class in Lyx 2.0.6.

Sorry for my newbie-ness....

Comment: I am sorry Fran, but I don't understand what you are suggesting I do.

Comment: I know how to add stuff to the preamble, but I don't know what to add specifically. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be a very good idea, but adding some `\vspace` in `\addtokomafont` seemed to work fine in the quick little test I did. Go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble, and add

```
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\vspace{2ex}}
```

Change `2ex` to the length of your choice. `\addtokomafont`/`\setkomafont` is intented to be used to change the formatting (font size, weight, etc.) of various document elements (see table 3.2 in the (English) manual for KOMA-script).

A complete minimal LaTeX example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\vspace{2cm}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\section{a}
Some text.
\subsubsection*{dd}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection*{dd}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why it would be a bad idea, but it seems to work great so far.

Comment: @forkandwait Me neither to be honest, but I don't really know exactly what that does, so I don't know if there are any possible side effects that are unwanted. On the other hand, I may just be a bit silly.

Answer (score 2):

For a `scrreprt` class you can redefine directly the `\subsection` command. For example:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection%
{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}%
{-23.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Note that  you must change `-23.5ex` to the desired space (by default is `-3.5ex`). The complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection%
{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}%
{-23.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{example}
\section{Example}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

> [image: MWE]

In a standard class as `article` you can obtain a similar effect adding this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{-10pt}{6em}{1em}
```

Experiment with this three lengths as you want, in this case `6em` is the vertical spacing). Note that here the negative values are to reduce spacing).

For more information, run `texdoc titlesec` from the command line or go [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).

Comment: I thought titlesec and Koma Script are incompatible.  Maybe I only get one or the other... (tradeoffs are everything..) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec.  Thanks for all your help, though.

Comment: @forkandwait Sorry, I forgot that the probelm is in a KOMA report class. I have little time now, but will I'll change the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: No sorry's necessary, I appreciate the help.  I will try titlesec -- I don't think KOMA is always incompatible, from reading.

Comment: @forkandwait Please see the update answer.