# How do I customize the font and font size of every section title once and for all?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\sect}[1]{\section{\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont \ctxfr #1}}

\begin{document}
\sect{Yes}

\end{document}
```

Above is what I tried; it is unfortunately not workable ('\ctxfr' is to specify a certain font).

Comment: Is this relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/formatting-section-titles

Comment: @jak123 Thank you; I tried that, which did not work in my case. :) But maybe it is because I was not "copying" it right...

Comment: @jak123 Sorry; I mis-typed the stuff that I tried; please refer to the present version if you are still willing; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few options for this. First with `sectsty` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\section{Yes}
Some text here

\end{document}
```

For font sizes like 20, you need a scalable font like `lmodern` The `phv` font family is used for demo.

Now with `titlesec`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\section{Yes}
Some text here

\end{document}
```

Please note that the `\titleformat*` is the short hand version. The enhanced version will be like below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}


\begin{document}
\section{Yes}
Some text here

\end{document}
```

The raw deal will be to change the original defintion manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont\bfseries}}  %% this line changed
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Yes}
Some text here

\end{document}
```