# Uppercase, bold and underlined chapter title

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I have my document like this (in `main.tex`):

```
% Document type: report (master/bachelor thesis)
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,appendix]{report}

\input{template/FormatsAndDefs.tex} % here I have specified various format settings

\begin{document}
  \input{thesis.tex}
\end{document}
```

In `FormatsAndDefs.tex` I have specified format for chapter titles like this:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% various other packages

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter}{.5em}{\vspace{.5ex}}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}      
    {0pt}{0pt}{15pt}
```

So my title chapters are formatted like this:
[image]

How can I make this chapter title "Introducion" in ALL UPPERCASE while keeping it bold and underlined?

I have tried to use `\MakeUppercase` :

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter}}{.5em}{\vspace{.5ex}}[\titlerule]
```

but chapter remained still the same as shown in the picture.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think you may in part be looking for the `\MakeUppercase` command. Does the second piece of code in [Gonzalo Medina's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36611/106162) to [Formatting section titles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36609/106162) help you?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have tried those solutions, but it gave me errors, because I am not sure where to add `\MakeUppercase` command in my `\titleformat` code.

Comment: Ok, if you can add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that would help us figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Try loading `titlesec` using the `explicit` option as `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}` and then `\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{.5em}{\MakeUppercase{#1}\vspace{.5ex}}[\titlerule]`.

Comment: @DaiBowen thanks, this works similary to Werner's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have a handle on the chapter title, and the only way to do this is to use the `explicit` option with [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter \quad \MakeUppercase{#1}}{.5em}{\vspace{.5ex}}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This option allows you to `explicit`ly state the sectional title as `#1`, where you can now wrap it within `\MakeUppercase`.

Comment: Ok, now my `\chapter` titles are uppercase and as I wanted them BUT my `\section` titles are underlined AS WELL... and I dont want them underlined. There is code right under the chapter title format :

`\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}`
As you can see there is no `[\titlerule]` specified. What is this strange behaviour?

Comment: @PeterB.: I don't get that in my output when I use `\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection \quad #1}{1em}{}`...

Comment: It was my mistake, because I deleted and replaced `\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks]{titlesec}` but I just needed to add `explicit` to square brackets. Now it works like a charm, thank you sir.

Comment: Would you please try `\chapter*{whatever}`?

Comment: @egreg: You'll have to read the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) to see the author discourages this.

Comment: Whatever Javier thinks about it, your code is wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 12):

Use the correct places for the various parts: the spacing before the rule should go in the last argument (the optional one), so you can finish the title argument with a one parameter macro such as `\MakeUppercase`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}
  {.5em}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  [\vspace{.5ex}\titlerule]

\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}
  {0pt}
  {15pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to set the thickness of the line with your code?

Comment: I guess I found the way to set the line thickness: ```[\vspace{0ex}{\titlerule[2pt]}]```