# Colorize headings in document and TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color, bookmarks

I want to colorize (highlight) certain headings both in the document as well as in the table of contents. The following works fine for me, but the respective entries in the `hyperref` TOC (links shown in the side bar of the PDF viewer) start with the word blue now.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
 colorlinks,
 pdfpagelabels,
 bookmarksnumbered, linkcolor = black,
 plainpages = false, hypertexnames = false, citecolor = black,
 urlcolor = blue,
 breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\SBlue}[1]{%
\begingroup\color{blue}{\textbf{#1}}\endgroup%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\vspace{10em}

\section{Heading 1}
foo
\section{\SBlue{Heading 2}}
bar
\section{Heading 3}
foobar

\end{document}
```

Here's what appears in the sidebar:

```
Heading 1
blueHeading 2
Heading 3
```

Is there a way of modifying the hyperref link texts? Or a completely different approach?

--Vic

Comment: you might rather modify the `\section` template like in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/formatting-section-titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents for the `PDF` bookmark panel should not consist of TeX macros, so `\color{blue}` etc. is nothing that `PDF` understands.

Use `\texorpdfstring{\color{blue}{\textbf{#1}}{#1}` where the second usage of `#1` will enter the `PDF` bookmarks.

The colour can be controlled with `\bookmarksetup{color=blue,bold}`, if bold is not requested, just omit it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[
 colorlinks,
 pdfpagelabels,
 bookmarksnumbered, linkcolor = black,
 plainpages = false, hypertexnames = false, citecolor = black,
 urlcolor = blue,
 breaklinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\bookmarksetup{color=blue,bold}

\newcommand{\SBlue}[1]{%
%\begingroup
\texorpdfstring{\color{blue}\textbf{#1}}{#1}%
%\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\vspace{10em}

\section{Heading 1}
foo
\section{\SBlue{Heading 2}}
bar
\section{Heading 3}
foobar

\end{document}
```

Comment: Es sind immer diese kleinen Dinge, die den fortgeschrittenen Anwender vom Guru unterscheiden ;-)   Der fortgeschrittene Anwender weiß gar nicht, wo er den Hebel ansetzen soll ...

Comment: @Victor: Ein weiser Spruch ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After fiddeling with Christian's solution around a bit more, here's my final code:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  pdfpagelabels,
  bookmarksnumbered, linkcolor = black,
  plainpages = false, hypertexnames = false, citecolor = black,
  urlcolor = blue,
  breaklinks]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{bookmark}

 \newcommand{\sectionB}[1]{
 \bookmarksetup{color=[rgb]{0,0,1}, bold}
 \section{\texorpdfstring{\color{blue}\textbf{#1}}{#1}}
 \bookmarksetup{color={}, bold=false}
 }

 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents
 \vspace{10em}

 \section{Header 1}
 foo
 \sectionB{Header 2}
 bar
 \section{Header 3}
 foobar

 \end{document}
```

(I only changed from xcolor to color because I have it loaded anyway and don't want to test the impact on my existing documents.)

Comment: Aha... Die Lösung entakzeptieren und dann die eigene bevorzugen. .. Das ist nicht koscher. Vor allem weil man nie von alleine auf diese Lösung gekommen wäre

Comment: Okay sorry ... ich glaube, das geht Dir ans Charma - richtig? Bin nicht so oft hier (nur wenn ich Probleme habe ;-). Hab's rückgängig gemacht.

Comment: One word to xcolor vs. color: I have a LOT of documents (i.e. user manuals) which I would have to check for compatibility problems ... as long as color works for me, I'm hesitating to make the change.

Comment: Das hat mit Karma nichts zu tun...