# how to customize my headers?

Tags: header-footer, lyx, titles, lyx-layouts

I want my part/section title to have underlined and be bald and increase its size.
I can't find how to make the wanted setting stay as my default. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/formatting-section-titles)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\underline\textbf\Large}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{This is a chapter}
    \section{This is your section}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: how do I do this in lyx?